# Making an AJAX call in React after a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, typescript

I'm pretty new to React, but I'm trying to have an AJAX call triggered when a specific button is pressed. I'm using the XMLHttpRequest method in this way:

```
getAssessment() {
    const data = this.data //some request data here
    const url = this.url   // API URL
    const promiseObj = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open('POST', url, true)
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data))
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log('Request processed successfully')
            const resp = xhr.responseText
            const respJson = JSON.stringify(resp)
            resolve(respJson)
          } 
        }
      }
    }})
    return promiseObj
  }
```

In my base.tsx file, I have a simple React component class defined:

```
class DecisionBase extends React.Component<any, any> {
...
public render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button
                   onClick = {//what can i put here?}
                >Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
}
```

In all the online sources that I've read, this AJAX call is placed in the `componentDidMount()` method. I intend to extract the data from the API as well, so I'm not sure how to design this aspect. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of times we are trying to fetch some data to display when a component mounts, so many tutorials are geared towards showing how to do that in `componentDidMount`. It is a good practice to factor your data wrangling functions to be their own entities. This allows for the second common type of data fetching, some state or prop changed and it needs to be refetched, in other words in `componentDidUpdate`.

It may sound overly simple, but just set the callback.

```
<button
  onClick={this.getAssessment}
>
  Submit
</button>
```

Or as an anonymous function

```
<button
  onClick={() => this.getAssessment()}
>
  Submit
</button>
```

It looks like `getAssessment` is actually *just* the function to make the request and return the promise. You can create an `onClickHandler` that invokes `getAssessment` and either awaits it's resolution to update state, or uses the returned Promise's promise chain.

```
onClickHandler = () => {
  this.getAssessment()
    .then(...) // <-- update state with response data
    .catch(...) // <-- or set some error state maybe?
}
```

Then use as callback

```
<button
  onClick={this.onClickHandler}
>
  Submit
</button>
```